# Different results of CPU and GPU with Theano

Tags: gpu, cpu, shared, theano

I have the following piece of code:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

x = theano.shared(np.asarray([1, 2, 3], dtype=theano.config.floatX), borrow=True)
y = T.cast(x, 'int32')
print 'type of y: ', type(y)
print 'type of y.owner.inputs[0]: ', type(y.owner.inputs[0])
print 'value of y: ', y.owner.inputs[0].get_value(borrow=True)
```

**Run with CPU**

```
$ THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=cpu,floatX=float32 python test_share.py
type of y:  <class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>
type of y.owner.inputs[0]:  <class 'theano.tensor.sharedvar.TensorSharedVariable'>
value of y:  [ 1.  2.  3.]
```

**Run with GPU**

```
$ THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32 python test_share.py
Using gpu device 0: GeForce 310M
type of y:  <class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>
type of y.owner.inputs[0]:  <class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>
value of y:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_share.py", line 10, in <module>
    print 'value of y: ', y.owner.inputs[0].get_value(borrow=True)
AttributeError: 'TensorVariable' object has no attribute 'get_value'
```

How can I get the same results as CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are using to access child nodes in the computation graph, `.owner.inputs[0]`, is not appropriate for cross-platform code in general.

You call the shared variable `x` so the correct way to access `x`'s value is to use `x.get_value()`.

This code should run the same on CPU and GPU:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

x = theano.shared(np.asarray([1, 2, 3], dtype=theano.config.floatX), borrow=True)
y = T.cast(x, 'int32')
print 'type of y: ', type(y)
print 'type of x: ', type(x)
print 'value of x: ', x.get_value(borrow=True)
```

If you want to see the result of applying the symbolic cast operation to `x`, the symbolic result of which you call `y`, then you could do this:

```
print 'value of y: ', y.eval()
```